# some design issue in ASP MVC project (Software Engineering question)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web app that has a few models,
my database calls wrapped in a class library.

I need to get a collection of items from the database (one of my model class),
but clearly the model is unknown to the database class lib.
I can define the item class in the database class lib instead of the web app but it doesn't look right.

is there a known solution to this situation?

I was thinking of two options:

1. define another class library that holds all the models, and add references to the app and database lib.
2. return dataset or datatable from the database class library and convert it to the items collection in my web app.

please advise

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software engineering design concepts and is too broad for Stack Overflow (perhaps better suited for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could structure your application:

1. Models (contains POCO objects that represent your business entities)
2. Repositories (contains CRUD operations with the models, this is the data access layer using a specific data access technology)
3. Services (contains business operations with the models which are achieved through the repositories)
4. MVC application which contains view models, controllers and views

So the MVC application uses the service layer to fetch a model from the database, maps this model to a view model and passes the view model to the view. The mapping between the models and the view models could be simplified with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com).

Comment: so basically my first option is the right one. I just don't understand why do I need another tier between my database and my web app? why using web service and not the class library? Thanks guys

Comment: @Avi, when I talk about *Services* this doesn't necessary means *web services*. It could be but it could also be a class library. It's just the business service layer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the common approach is to have your domain entities live somewhere other than your web project. You can then map from these entities to your view specific models. Using your own mapping framework or something like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).